# LINQ QueryProvider Select

Tags: c#, linq, select, iqueryable

I am trying to write a simple QueryProvider for a selection and keep failing. This is my example query:

```
var query = from elem in MyIQueryableImplementation
            select new {Name = elem.Name};
```

It is followed by a foreach statement that calls:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IEnumerable<T>)this.provider.Execute(this.expression)).GetEnumerator();
}
```

Which invokes (ignoring the expression tree for now):

```
public override object Execute(Expression expression)
{
       return Exec();
}
```

And then:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> Exec()
{
     for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        yield return new {Name = "TEST"};
     } 
     yield break;
}
```

Running this, it throws the exception (in the GetEnumerator() call):

```
Unable to cast object of type '<Exec>d__0' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]]'.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are Exec and the query in different assemblies?

Comment: Does it work when you just return the string instead of an anonymous type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IEnumerable` returned from Exec is an `IEnumerable<object>`. It happens to return elements of a type derived from object, but its interface type is just `IEnumerable<object>`. That's why you can't cast it to `IEnumerable1[<>f__AnonymousType01[System.String]]`.

You can cast it element-wise, though:

```
return ((IEnumerable)this.provider.Execute(this.expression)).Cast<T>().GetEnumerator();
```

Comment: This works, thanks.  A quick follow-up question: For an a bit more complex version of the problem, the Exec() method has to be in a different assembly. Here I again receive an exception: [A]<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String] cannot be cast to [B]<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]. Type A originates from ...  What can I do in this case?

Comment: Convert the anonymous type to a named class so you can reference it cross-assembly by name.

Comment: The assembly that contains Exec() is dynamically created by the library at run-time, so it would be possible to create the named class there (depending on the content of the Expression tree). However, the assembly that contains the LINQ query is outside the library and should support the use of anonymous types. Any other solutions?

Comment: My understanding was that the hard-coded result set in `Exec` is just a temporary hack. I thought that your LINQ provider would create the results dynamically, using either reflection or a variant of reflection emit (emit or expression trees). In that case `Exec` would adapt at runtime to the requested element type. It would find out which type is requested and construct it. This is how the popular ORMs work.

Comment: You are right, `Exec` is just a temporary hack, but the actual implementation is supposed to be part of C# code that is dynamically generated and compiled with CodeDOM. Hence it will be in a different assembly and I will run into the same problem.

Comment: @user1622959 ok that won't work with dynamic types because they cannot be mentioned in a C# program. You probably should switch to generating lightweight functions using expression trees.

Comment: Please let me know if the following is correct: 1) I cannot create an anonymous type (via code generation, reflection or emit) in assembly A and then return it to assembly B; 2) I can create an expression tree that contains the constructor of an anonymous type and method calls for the constructor's arguments in A, return it to B, compile it there and then execute it; 3) Anonymous types in LINQ queries only work if the QueryProvider is in the same assembly as the query statement.

Comment: 1) you *can* create anonymous types, you just won't be able to reference them from C# in another assembly as they have a generated name. There is no difference between anon types and normal types at the IL level. They are just named differently (like "<>garbage123" which is an invalid identifier in C#). 2) yes. Expression trees and emit can reference anon types (because there is no difference to normal types when it comes to IL or reflection!) 3) not at all.; You can check yourself if you got it: Describe to yourself the difference between anonymous types and normal types (or read it up).

Comment: Your response to 3) suggests that there is still something that I entirely don't understand. Take the code blocks from my original question as example and assume the first block is in a different assembly than all the remaining code blocks. `GetEnumerator()` has to return an Enumerator of Type _<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]_. But, however the instances of _<>f__AnonymousType0`1_ is created in the Enumerator, when returned to the other assembly, the exception from my first comment should occur again because both anonymous classes stem from different assemblies. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If GetEnumerator returns [RightAssembly].[<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]] it will succeed. If it returns [WrongAssemlby].[<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]] it would fail. A type has its identity defined by a combination of assembly and type name, not just type name. So Exec really has to create instances of the type defined in the assembly of its caller. Exec could be implemented like this: `yield return Activator.CreateInstance(elementType)`. Where elementType would be the runtime type that the sequence elements should have.

Comment: So `elementType` is the type of the anonymous type created in assembly _A_; `yield return Activator.CreateInstance(elementType)` is called in assembly _B_ (`elementType` is obtained from the Expression tree), but will create an instance of the anonymous type of assembly _A_ and, hence, it will work once it is returned to _A_. Am I correct this time? Btw, thanks for all the replies, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're correct. To B, it is transparent which type is requested (anonymous or not). All it cares about is that it can obtain a reference to a `Type` at runtime that represents the element type. It can reason about its members using reflection and so on.